navController.findDestination returns error: NavController.findDestination can only be called from within the same library group
My code below was working before I update to the latest version of androidx.navigation:navigation and safeargs
private lateinit var navView: BottomNavigationView
private lateinit var navController: NavController
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragmentActivityMain) as NavHostFragment?
val inflater = navHostFragment!!.navController.navInflater
val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.bottom_navigation)

navController = navHostFragment.navController
val navArgument1= NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(email).build()
val navArgument2= NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(jwt).build()
graph.addArgument("email",navArgument1)
graph.addArgument("jwt",navArgument2)
navHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.home -> {
                    navController.findDestination(R.id.home)!!.addArgument("email", NavArgument.Builder()
                        .setDefaultValue(email)
                        .build())
}
                R.id.deliver -> {
                    navController.findDestination(R.id.userDelivery)!!.addArgument("email", NavArgument.Builder()
                        .setDefaultValue(email)
                        .build())
                    navController.findDestination(R.id.userDelivery)!!.addArgument("jwt", NavArgument.Builder()
                        .setDefaultValue(jwt)
                        .build())
                    navController.navigate(R.id.userDelivery)
                }
}
           

Now at all the navController.findDestination lines up there, it will display the error NavController.findDestination can only be called from within the same library group
What should be changed here?
